# How to activate a ScrollBar?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm starting to learn how to program and I have a problem.
I am making an application in C # WPF.
I want to put a scrollbar on a grid and not activate it.
I searched and tried several things I found, but I have not gotten it right.
As the window is larger than the monitor, what I want is to put a scrollbar to access the bottom of the window.
The last thing I tried is this.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="921*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollBar Height="921" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="761,0,0,0" Name="scrollBar1" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12" Maximum="960" Minimum="1" SmallChange="1" />
</Grid>
```

With this comes the scrollbar, but the window does not move.
Thanks in advance and forgive for writing. I made it with google translator.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You also have to wrap your Grid inside the ScrollBar for it to work. Also get rid of the Height, Width and Margin Properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content that you wish to scroll should be a child of a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx).

```
<ScrollViewer>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="921*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

For the purposes of layout, The child is assumed to have infinite avaliable width and height. This means that the child of a scrollviewer will never behave as it would with restricted space (unless you set maxwidth / maxheight).

Comment: Thanks for answering so soon. I tried what you said and it works for me.Thank you very much.